# Handle mouse vs touch events via event.type

Tags: typescript

I have a general handler function that takes in an event that can either be a mouse or touch event. Then it delegates the logic to the appropriate function. Typescript is throwing errors, though, because obviously `mouseEvent !== touchEvent`.

```
function handleStopDrag(e: MouseEvent | TouchEvent) {
    switch (e.type) {
        case 'mouseup':
            // Error: Argument of type 'MouseEvent | TouchEvent' is not assignable to parameter of type 'MouseEvent'.
            handleMouseUp(e)
            break
        case 'touchcancel':
        case 'touchend':
            // Error: Argument of type 'MouseEvent | TouchEvent' is not assignable to parameter of type 'TouchEvent'.
            handleTouchEnd(e)
            break
    }
}

function handleMouseUp(e: MouseEvent){ ... }
function handleTouchEnd(e: TouchEvent) { ... }
```

How do I go about declaring that the event type is a specific type based on my checks above? Or is there a better way of formatting my code to specify the event type?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use a [type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards) to enable TypeScript to narrow the `MouseEvent | TouchEvent` union type to either `MouseEvent` or `TouchEvent` type without having to resort to type assertion (`<MouseEvent> e` or `e as MouseEvent`):

- With type predicates:

```
function isMouseEvent(e: MouseEvent | TouchEvent): e is MouseEvent {
    return e.type === 'mouseup'; // || e.type === 'click'...
}
```

then use it like

```
if (isMouseEvent(e)) {
    switch (e.type) {
        case 'mouseup':
            handleMouseUp(e);
            break;
} else (isTouchEvent(e)) {
    switch (e.type) {
        case 'touchcancel':
        case 'touchend':
            handleTouchEnd(e);
            break;
}
```

- With `instanceof`:

```
if (e instanceof MouseEvent) {
    // switch specific MouseEvent type here or inside another delegator
    handleMouseEvent(e);
} else if (e instanceof TouchEvent) {
    handleTouchEvent(e);
}
```

Comment: Just for additional precision: TypeScript is quite sensitive to how you use your type guard: the "isMouseEvent(e)" must be in the if (can't be stored in a variable) ; the type has to be "evt is MouseEvent" precisely, not boolean ; using just "else" won't work, you explicitely need the "else if (isTouchEvent(e))". It may make the code a bit verbose but that's worth it.

Answer (score 2):

By using `in` operator to check for a property that does not exist in both Typescript was able to figure out every other thing, with less effort from my own end

```
function dragStart(e: MouseEvent | TouchEvent) {
  if ('touches' in e) {
    state.initialX = e.touches[0].clientX - state.xOffset
    state.initialY = e.touches[0].clientY - state.yOffset
  } else {
    state.initialX = e.clientX - state.xOffset
    state.initialY = e.clientY - state.yOffset
  }

}
```